# Entity Framework returns 0 results in spite of the data in the tables when `DbFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, c.ModifiedDate)` is used in the query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

The below code should return the result from the `table` which has `status = 1` and the data is older than `90 days`. In the `table` there are a lot of data which has `modified date` more than`90 days`.

But this code is returning 0 results.
The `datetime` difference throws error so used `DbFunctions` instead since EF I am using is EF6.

```
IEnumerable<IncentiveClaim> claims = repository.Table
                      .Where(c => c.Status == 1 
                        && DbFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, c.ModifiedDate) >= 90)
                      .AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: What is the value of `DateTime.Now` on your PC? What is the **exact** value of `c.ModifiedDate` that you are expecting to be returned? _BTW, you could do this without `DiffDays` altogether._ Do you perhaps have the dates the wrong way around?

Comment: Could you try `c.ModifiedDate <= bob` where `bob` is set to `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90)` **before** the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method has parameter as `DbFunctions.DiffDays(smallestDateTime, LargestDateTime)`. So, the `ModifiedDate` should be first parameter and `DateTime.Now` should be second parameter. Then, you have to call `.Value` on the method to get the `no. of days`.

Modify the code as below:

```
IEnumerable<IncentiveClaim> claims = repository.Table
           .Where(c => c.Status == 1 
            && DbFunctions.DiffDays(c.ModifiedDate, DateTime.Now).Value >= 
            90)
            .ToList();
```